# what is the use of Private Classes in C#

Tags: c#

why we create private classes in c#? As we know that private class couldn't be make base class and we couldn't derived the classes from them.And what is the use and purpose of private class?

Comment: For the same reason that we have private anything. And what's the other thing we do with classes other than derive from them? Oh, that's right, we *instantiate* them -- or call their static members. Why does your question ignore those uses of classes?

Comment: This question may be (well, is) a bad one, but it's not "primarily opinion-based", so the close votes are bogus. The OP is simply mistaken to assume that the only purpose of classes is to derive from them, but never to *use* them. Going past that error, the question is simply why there are private entities of any sort, and that's well-established, not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Private classes (or private anything, really) are important because control of scope is important, due to the notion of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

If you are building a library with "private" (`internal`) classes, your library can use those classes while anyone using your library will not be able to even see them.  This can hide implementation-specific details that you wish to conceal.

If you are building a class that has private nested classes, the containing class can use those private classes without anyone else being able to see them.  Again, you can use this to hide implementation-specific details that you wish to conceal.

If you don't hide implementation-specific details (e.g. by making a private or internal class public) then it becomes more difficult to change the implementation, since you can't be sure that users of your library haven't created dependencies on those classes.  But if they are non-public, you can change them, replace them, or remove them, all without any worry of disrupting external dependencies.

Comment: "If you are building a library will private classes...": you'd typically make those classes `internal`.

Comment: "If you are building a library will private classes..." It's impossible to even do that. You would get a CS1527 error.

Answer (score 4):

Private classes can only be created inside nested classes and are used to retrict access and to only be used inside this nested class.

Comment: I think you mean that private classes can only *be* nested classes ... they don't have to be inside nested classes. They can only be used *by* the outer class.

Answer (score 3):

It is widely considered to be a good practice to divide our code up into separate logical units. Each unit has a limited number of reponsibilities that are all related. That makes it easier to test the code, and once it is well-tested, those units become building blocks with which we can create more complex patterns. Private classes are useful for creating building blocks that are implementing internal functionality that you don't necessarily want visible to other projects using a library. They can also implement interfaces, and thus are useful if you want to set up a factory so that you control what instances of the class get made -- callers can then still use the class via the interface, even though they can't see the class type itself.